# Prevent Nancy from Caches all file system path evaluations

Tags: nancy

I'm facing a problem that the size of my static content directory is too big and contains a lot of sub-directories( about 22 GB) and when I run my code it takes about 30 mins to create a new instance from NancyHost because it scans all the sub-directories in the main directory for better performance.Below is the code on how I specify the static content directory and how I create the nancy host

```
public class ApplicationBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
        {
            protected override void ConfigureConventions(NancyConventions nancyConventions)
            {
                nancyConventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("/", @"MyDirectory"));
                base.ConfigureConventions(nancyConventions);
            }
        }

ApplicationBootstrapper ApplicationBootstrapper = new ApplicationBootstrapper();
                nancyHost = new NancyHost(ApplicationBootstrapper, new Uri(String.Format("http://localhost:{0}/", NancyPort)));
                nancyHost.Start();
```

My question is how to prevent nacny from scanning the directory on the startup?